# How to get the inserted or updated object after insert and update sql in mybatis

Tags: mybatis

Is there any way to get the newly inserted or updated object after insert/update sql query in mybatis? Or I have to run the select query to retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the generated key from an insert statement (`keyProperty`, `keyColumn`, `useGeneratedKeys`).

You already have the values for properties/columns inserted/updated.

You cannot retrieve values from columns not inserted (column default value) or updated (record column current value).

Then you have to select these values.